# Are there any orbit test theorems for Lie groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Suppose I have continuous group (or Lie group) formed by a smooth transformation $T_{a}$ (not necessarily linear or matrix-like) acting on a function $f(x,y)$ that maps to some other set of functions (or just a mapping between general function spaces which are not necessarily complete) for $x,y \in [a,b] \times [c,d].$

Are there any group-like theorems that would let me test or determine whether another given function $g(x)$ is in the orbit of the action of $T_{a}[f(x)]$?

Comment: In this degree of generality, this is pretty hopeless.

Comment: It's definitely not hopeless, it simply may not be known by today's mathematics. From your own knowledge however, what level of specificity would be required to make it certain? The Banach fixed point theorem can take an entire infinitely dimensional space, not just one isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2,$ but something that isn't even comprehensible and has no physical comparison, yet say there exists one unique fixed point under a linear contraction operator. A Lie group is more or less just a continuous group which gives it more topological properties that finite-point sets lack.

Comment: The only algorithmic (and I think this is what your question is about) results I am aware of are in the following context: $f$ is a polynomial function of $n$ variables, $G$ is an algebraic subgroup of $GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ acting on the ring of polynomial functions in $n$ variables. Then one can test the membership of a function $g(x_1,...,x_n)$ in the $G$-orbit of $f$. Incidentally, it is unclear what you mean by  "a continuous group (or a Lie group) formed by a smooth transformation $T_a$": One transformation hardly ever forms a group.